# mpl_finance.candlestick2_ohlc returns a blank graph when given a subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, quantitative-finance

Below is my code that is giving me difficulties. I am trying to plot a line chart as the top row with a dynamically created number of subplots below, at least one of which will be a candlestick chart.

When I graph the candlestick2_ohlc by itself, without creating a subplot for it and without graphing any other subplot, it works perfectly. When I try to use subplots and include the other graphs, however, It turns out having everything graphed perfectly, except the candlesticks are completely missing. I have no idea what would cause this behavior, however I know that no other graphs are overriding it on the same plot. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
def plot(self):
    def mydate(x, pos):
        '''function for labeling xticks as datetime objects'''
        try:
            return self.broker.data.index[int(x)]
        except IndexError:
            return ''

    totalPlots = 1
    plotNum = 1
    for indicator in self.indicators:
        if not indicator.plotWithData:
            totalPlots += 1
    for data in self.broker.data:
        totalPlots += 1

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()


    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tickerGraph.MaxNLocator(10))  # number of xtick labels
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tickerGraph.FuncFormatter(mydate))  # use nested method to label xticks
    plt.subplot(int(str(str(totalPlots) + '1' + str(plotNum))))  # top plot is always account value
    plt.title('Account Value')

    plt.plot(list(self.broker.data.values())[0].df.index, self.broker.valueData)

    for ticker in self.broker.data.keys():
        plotNum += 1
        plt.subplot(int(str(str(totalPlots) + '1' + str(plotNum))))
        plt.title(ticker)
        candlestick2_ohlc(ax=ax, opens=self.broker.data[ticker].df['open'], highs=self.broker.data[ticker].df['high'],
                          lows=self.broker.data[ticker].df['low'], closes=self.broker.data[ticker].df['close'],
                          width=.6, colorup='g', colordown='r')

        for trade in self.plotTrades[ticker]:
            plt.scatter(list(self.broker.data.values())[0].df.index[trade.index], self.broker.data[ticker].df.iloc[trade.index]['close'], c=trade.color) ##IMPROVE

        for indicator in self.indicators:
            if indicator.plotWithData:
                plt.plot(indicator.ydata[ticker])

    for indicator in self.indicators:
        if not indicator.plotWithData:
            plotNum += 1[enter image description here][1]
            plt.subplot(int(str(str(totalPlots) + '1' + str(plotNum))))
            plt.plot(indicator.ydata[ticker])
            plt.title(indicator.name + ' ' + ticker)

    plt.show()
```

Here is what the weird, blank graph looks like:

[image: Generated graph]

Comment: It might just be behind all other plots? I'd recommend either only using `fig, arrayofax = plt.subplots(totalPlots+1, 1)` *or* `plt.figure()` followed by individual `plt.subplot(...)`. (Btw. `plt.subplot(totalPlots, 1, n)` is much more readable than the string casting you perform.) Please also read [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by behind?  I tried the same thing without the scatter and it was still blank.  Thank you for the recommendation, I totally forgot about the comma syntax for subplots.  I'll also try specifying the subplots.

Comment: I guess I can only help further with a [mcve].